# issue in install tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pip, carla

when I use pip install tensorflow command that error appear :-
'''
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210601 requires gast==0.4.0, but you have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210601 requires h5py~=3.1.0, but you have h5py 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
tf-nightly 2.6.0.dev20210601 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.18.5 which is incompatible.'''

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install Tensorflow and tf-nightly on the same environment. Since Tensorflow and tf-nightly uses same code, you should never install both in same environment. Latest version overrides the most of the packages, thats how `pip` works. It recommended to use virtual environment each tensorflow version.
Tf-nightly require gast==0.4.0 and numpy==1.19.2.

Follow the below steps

```
python -m tf_nightly --system-site-packages .\venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tf-nightly
```